# When is it correct to treat differential(e.g. $dx$) as regular number

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Many times I saw that people tread differentials as regular numbers. They for example multiply by them or divide. E.g. below there is multiplication of $\frac{df(x)}{d (x^2)}$ by $\frac{1/dx}{1/dx}$

$$\frac{df(x)}{d (x^2)} = \frac{df(x)/dx}{d(x^2)/dx} = \frac{1}{2 x} \frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

My question is when it is legal to do such things? Always in some specific cases? Are there some formal theories that formalize this nice trick?

Answer (score 2):

The symbols $dx$, $dy$, etc. can be thought of as "infinitesimals," which is how Newton thought of these (roughly speaking).  As the article below states, a rigorous approach to infinitesimals was undertaken in the 1960s.

http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/infincalc.htm

There are many other references; just search nonstandard analysis.

And to answer the original question, as long as you treat $dx$ as a nonzero number smaller than any real number and such that $(dx)^2$ is equivalent to $0$ when taking sums, you can get away with the construction you showed in your question.

For example, if $f(x) = x^2$, then

$$df = (x+dx)^2 - x^2 = x^2 + 2xdx + (dx)^2 - x^2 \equiv 2xdx$$

Comment: Where is this $(dx)^2=0$ coming from?

Comment: Ok, I think I have found the answer in the given homepage ($\varepsilon$ as the infinitesimal $dx$):
"Note that there is no necessity of $\varepsilon^2$ being zero; it just has to have zero effect on the equivalence class that a sum belongs to."

Comment: @Berci, so yes there is some sort of distinction between literally being $0$ and just acting as $0$ in sums.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the chain rule $\frac{\mathrm d (f\circ g)}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dg}\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dx}$, which gives you $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dg} = \frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{-1}$ whenever $f,\ g\in C^1$ (and possibly some other assumption on the derivative of g in x).

Comment: See my comment to Babak Sorouh answer.

Comment: Yeah, I did a quite big abuse of notation. the right form of the expression would be $\frac{\mathrm d(f\circ g)}{\mathrm dg}(x) = f'(g(x))(g'(x))^{-1}$, where the -1 is an exponent, not an inverse.

Comment: Chain rule says  $\frac{\mathrm d (f\circ g)}{\mathrm dx} = f'(g(x))g'(x)$. I do not know from where -1 exponent came.

Comment: Yes, but my first derivative is in g, not in x. Take the chain rule and move the term g' on the other side, and you'll see.

Comment: It still does not answer question when you can operate on $dx$ as if it was regular number. I saw this trick many times and it simplifies things a lot. So I want to know when it is legal too use it almost mindlessly without thinking about underlying theories as chain rule.

Comment: Typically, if your functions are nice enough ($C^1$ is often good, if you have only 1st order derivatives). You still have to be attentive not to divide by zero, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have said this before, but it works out because the derivative is the limit of a ratio of 2 very small numbers.  So, the numbers may be maniuplated, so that $dy$ and $dx$ represent small quantities.  But the derivative is just that, and the notation $dy/dx$ is a mnemonic.  It is a testament to the clear thinking behind this notation that the Chain Rule resembles cancellation, thus making calculus that much easier for generations of students.